# How to fetch data asynchronously from server in iOS and update UI after receiving data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

In my iOS app, I am trying to fetch data from a server. I want to do this asynchronously. I am trying this:

```
 - (void)loadData {
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

  /** code for fetching data. **/

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    myList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:fetchedData, nil];
  });
 });


}
```

Above method loadData() is called from the init() method of the tableViewController.

I am using the data from objects in this list to be displayed as cells.
But before I receive the data from the server, the main thread tries to populate the UI from the list (which will obviously be empty). How do I sync those?

I have found that :

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

above function (which returns the count of myList) returns 0, and hence my table is displayed as empty. This function is called before I receive data from the server (since that takes more time, while this method is immediately transferred control in the main thread).

Comment: let me know your issue is over

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fetching data from server, just 'reload' your table once more. then 
the methods (numberOfRows, numberOfSections, ...) are called again.

> Call this method to reload all the data that is used to construct the table, including cells, section headers and footers, index arrays, and so on. For efficiency, the table view redisplays only those rows that are visible. It adjusts offsets if the table shrinks as a result of the reload. The table view’s delegate or data source calls this method when it wants the table view to completely reload its data. It should not be called in the methods that insert or delete rows, especially within an animation block implemented with calls to beginUpdates and endUpdates.

Check
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadData

```
 - (void)loadData {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

      /** code for fetching data. **/

      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        myList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:fetchedData, nil];
        yourTable.reloadData()  // <-- reload your table after update myList
      });
     });


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to check `AFNetworking`(https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking). In completion handler of `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` just set up your `tableView` `dataSource` and `delegates` and `reloadData()`. The other way is to reloadData in `tableView dataSource` setter method.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSString *stringURL = //ur url;

[manager GET:stringURL parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    if (completion) {
        //ur completion
    }
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    if (completion) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)loadData {
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

/** code for fetching data. **/

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    myList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:fetchedData, nil];
    [yourTable reloadData]; // reload the data

  });
 });


}
```

Answer (score -1):

you might wanna try to to call your loadData function after calling youre fetch function. in youre scenario loadData gets called first before youre fetch function which is why you always get an empty myList. call the fetch function first before you call loadData.

if you want to use async, you can also put your fetch function in your async but put a break point so that it wont always call it.

Comment: I didn't get you. I am not calling loadData() before fetch function. I am calling fetch function inside loadData().
Please read the whole question, I'm sure it will be clear.